# Custom 24 hour format to calculate difference between dates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have reported date & time in the format (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM) and resolved date & time in the same format. I would like to calculate the difference between the reported date & time and resolved date & time, excluding weekends (which are Friday and Saturday). Also, for ex: if the reported time is 10 PM it should count 1 day if it the resolved time is on or after 10pm the next day.

Comment: sample data, expected result, and what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in row 2, column A

If you have the start time in `A2`, and the resolved time in `B2`.

Since your data is cleanly in a Date/Time format, you can simply subtract the greater time period from the lesser.

This will give you the amount of days, and hour in decimals (hours as a percent of hours in the day).

```
=(B2-A2) ' Days and hours to resolve

=(B2-A2)*24 ' Hours it took to resolve
```